# What is the difference between `a[bc]d` (brackets) and `a{b,c}d` (braces)?

Tags: brace-expansion, pattern-matching

What is the difference between `a[bc]d` and `a{b,c}d`? Why do people use `a{b,c}d` when there is already `a[bc]d`?

Comment: Who told you to use `command a[bc]d`?

Comment: It certainly has its uses if one understands it correctly.

Comment: I guess I just don't understand how the confusion between the two happened.

Comment: I have been explicitly asked by a coworker less familiar with Linux on this, although not recently.

Comment: @Jesse_b If you only ever try them with operations on files like `ls` and you only ever try single characters, they would appear to work the same.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The two are quite different.

`a[bc]d` is a **filename pattern** (in shells other than `fish`). It will expand to the two *filenames* `abd` and `acd` if those are names of existing files in the current directory.

- The `[...]` part is a bracketed expression that matches a single character out of the ones listed (or collating elements when ranges are included).  To match the pattern `a[bc]d`, the character between the strings `a` and `d` in a filename must be either a `b` or a `c`.
- If `abd` exists, but `acd` does not, then it would only expand to `abd`, and vice versa.
- If neither `abd`, nor `acd` exist, depending on the shell and the options, it would trigger an error (original Unix `sh`, `(t)csh`, `zsh`, `fish`, `bash -O failglob`) and possibly exit the shell, or leave the pattern unexpanded¹ (Bourne-like and `rc`-like shells) or expand to nothing (`bash/zsh/yash -o nullglob`, some older versions of `fish`, original Unix `sh` and `(t)csh` if there are other matching globs in the same command).

`a{b,c}d` is a **brace expansion** (in shells that support these).  It will expand to the two *strings* `abd` and `acd`.

- The `{...}` part is a comma-delimited set of strings (in this example; in some shell, it may also be a range such as `a..k` or `20..25` or more advanced ones like `00..20..2` or `0..20..2%02d`), and the expansion is computed by combining each of these strings with the flanking strings `a` and `d`.  These strings could be longer than a single character and could also be brace expansions themselves.
- The expansion happens regardless of whether these strings corresponds to existing filenames or not.

If you are constructing strings, use a brace expansion.  If you are matching filenames, use a filename pattern.

---

<sup>¹ In this particular case, `a[bc]d` could happen to be the name of an existing file which is why it's potentially dangerous to use things like `rm -f ./*.[ch]` in those shells and `rm -f ./*.{c,h}` is less of a problem.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for clarifying "If abd exists, but acd does not, then it would only expand to abd". I guess that is what is missing from my answer.

Comment: Another crucial difference is that in `a{b,c}d`, the `b` and `c` parts don't need to be single letters; e.g. `ex{ten,ci}sion`. While `ex[tenci]sion` or whatever will only match _one_ of these letters.

Answer (score 7):

`a[bc]d` is **pattern-matching**, and is part of the POSIX standard. In POSIX, this is introduced as the "pattern bracket expression". It is documented in [section 2.13 of the manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_13)

> When unquoted and outside a bracket expression, the following three
>   characters shall have special meaning in the specification of
>   patterns:
>
>   ?
>     A question-mark is a pattern that shall match any character.
>   *
>     An asterisk is a pattern that shall match multiple characters, as
>       described in Patterns Matching Multiple Characters.
>   [
>     The open bracket shall introduce a pattern bracket expression.

Section 2.13.3 also mentions something that it behaves differently from what one would expect for usual regexs when it is used for filename expansion (emphasis by me)

> The rules described so far in Patterns Matching a Single Character and
>   Patterns Matching Multiple Characters are qualified by the following
>   rules that apply when pattern matching notation is used for filename
>   expansion:
>
> **The slash character in a pathname shall be explicitly matched by using
>   one or more slashes in the pattern; it shall neither be matched by the
>   asterisk or question-mark special characters nor by a bracket
>   expression. Slashes in the pattern shall be identified before bracket
>   expressions;** thus, a slash cannot be included in a pattern bracket
>   expression used for filename expansion. If a slash character is found
>   following an unescaped open square bracket character before a
>   corresponding closing square bracket is found, the open bracket shall
>   be treated as an ordinary character. For example, the pattern
>   `"a[b/c]d"` does not match such pathnames as `abd` or `a/d`.
>   It only matches a pathname of literally `a[b/c]d`.

`a{b,c}d` is **braces expansion**, it is not in the specification by POSIX. Here is the corresponding part from the bash [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) (emphasis by me):

> Brace expansion is a mechanism by which arbitrary **strings** may be
>   generated. This mechanism is similar to *filename expansion* (see
>   Filename Expansion), but **the filenames generated need not exist**.
>   Patterns to be brace expanded take the form of an optional *preamble,*
>   followed by either a series of comma-separated strings or a sequence
>   expression between a pair of braces, followed by an optional
>   *postscript.* The preamble is prefixed to each string contained within
>   the braces, and the postscript is then appended to each resulting
>   string, expanding left to right.

According to the comment by @mosvy, this first appeared from `csh` but the behavior in `bash` is different from `csh` and other shells. This type of braces expansion is also present in `glob(3)`.

There is another type of braces expansion `{a..z}` that only appeared after `bash` 3.0, and there are more added in `bash` 4.0.

In a shell where globbing is turned on, execute in a empty folder, the following result is returned

```
$ echo a[bc]d
a[bc]d
$ echo a{b,c}d
abd acd
```

In response to @Jesse_b's comment, if you are in an interactive shell and both of them applies, `a[bc]d` is less trouble typing. For example `grep pattern [ab][12].txt`.

Comment: The brace expansion is not a "bashism"; it first appeared in `csh`, long before `bash`. It's also present in the glob(3) library function. The difference is that in `bash` it's performed before other expansions: `a=A; ab=A/B; ac=A/C; echo $a{b,c}` will work in bash differently from any other shell.

Comment: Thank you. I will update the answer.